# Объединение результатов из нескольких таблиц с разной структурой

Tags: mysql, join, запрос, база-данных

Всем привет.

Столкнулся с проблемой объединения результатов запроса, который нужно получить из разных таблиц.

В общем, есть таблица новостей, пусть для простоты будет такая структура: id новости, заголовок, текст новости.

Есть таблица данных к новостям (пусть будут url картинок), структура: id данных, id новости, url картинки.

Каким образом можно "приклеить" к новости все ссылки на картинки?
То есть в идеале я хочу получить такое:
id новости, заголовок, текст новости, url картинки 1, url картинки 2, ...

LEFT JOIN/JOIN/RIGHT JOIN/... попробовал, прикрепляют только одну ссылку из всех. 
Если вложить SELECT, то mysql также не позволяет вытащить более 1-й ссылки, т.е. тоже не подходит.

Хранить сразу html-код или bb-коды с ссылками на картинки непосредственно в тексте новости не хочу, очень сильно теряется гибкость.

Вариант с двумя запросами (сначала вытащить новость, потом все картинки к ней) заставит переписывать почти весь код проекта, хотелось бы его оставить как самый крайний вариант, если уж других вариантов совсем нет.

Заранее спасибо за любую помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему это LEFT JOIN не подходит?

К примеру:

```
табл новостей
1|заголовок1|текст1
2|заголовок2|текст2
3|заголовок3|текст3

табл картинок
1|1|картинка1
2|1|картинка2
3|2|картинка3
4|2|картинка4
5|2|картинка5

Результатом запроса 
SELECT news.id, title, text, image FROM news LEFT JOIN images on news.id=newid

будет такая таблица
1|заголовок1|текст1|картинка1
1|заголовок1|текст1|картинка2
2|заголовок2|текст2|картинка3
2|заголовок2|текст2|картинка4
2|заголовок2|текст2|картинка5
.....
  обработка на php
$id=-10;
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) 
{
if ($id!=$data['id'])
   {
   //тут выводим новость и 1ую картинку
   $id= $data['id'];
   }
else
{
   //тут выводим остальные картинки текущей новости
   }
}
```

Comment: Так происходит дублирование новостей и я не представляю как мне потом обработать результат в php. 

Сейчас просто  
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {//тут выводим новость в нужном формате} 

Мне же нужно все эти картинки потом вставить непосредственно внутри новости так, как будет нужно. 

А при раскладе с LEFT JOIN я вытащу новость в $data и в ней будет только 1 ссылка, с которой я кашу не сварю и вывести не смогу пользователю, т.к. нужны остальные 10 ссылок на картинки к этой новости.

Либо я выведу пользователю одну и туже новость 10 раз и в каждой будет 1 картинка из желаемых 1

Comment: Тогда вопрос такой: а количество картинок к новости определено или может быть разной?

Comment: тогда попробуй два раза цикл сделать, в первом соберешь все картинки в массив, а во втором, уже выводишь свои новости и картинки

Comment: Обновил ответ, добавил обработку на php.

Comment: Количество картинок к каждой новости от 1 до 15. Я ещё рассматривал вариант с хранением в отдельном поле в таблице новостей, допустим с разделением через запятую. Но я так понимаю, это будет ещё больший изврат, или нет? Мне важно рассматривать задачу с точки зрения производительности на большом количестве записей.

Два цикла это всё равно что сделать второй запрос и отдельно вытащить все картинки к новости.

Comment: Я ещё рассматривал вариант с хранением в отдельном поле в таблице новостей, допустим, с разделением через запятую. В принципе большого изврата нет, у вас по новостям больше операций вывода, нежели редактирования - поэтому подходящий вариант.